# Software that provides easy FFT, DCT and or DWT to watermark images

Tags: image-processing, photography, image-editor, digital-watermarking

Is there a software package online that provides easy FFT, DCT, and/or DWT to watermark images? Even more specifically, JPG images. 
It should feature either batch file processing capabilities, or a CLI, or both.

I read the following article this evening, and I have come to the conclusion that transform domain changes will provide superior robustness over spatial domain techniques:

- [Using Watermarks to Prevent Leaks](http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/detection/watermarks-prevent-leaks-34087)
- [AN OVERVIEW OF IMAGE STEGANOGRAPHY](http://vanilla47.com/PDFs/Cryptography/Steganography/AN%20OVERVIEW%20OF%20IMAGE%20STEGANOGRAPHY.pdf)
- [Steganography and Digital Watermarking: a global view](http://www-lia.deis.unibo.it/Courses/RetiDiCalcolatori/Progetti00/fortini/project.pdf)
- [Steganalysis of Images Created Using Current Steganography Software](http://www.jjtc.com/ihws98/jjgmu.html)
- [Implementation of steganographic techniques in matlab: Project Report](http://www.academia.edu/5756954/Implementation_of_steganographic_techniques_in_matlab_Project_Report)

Originally, I wanted to experiment with [openpuff](http://embeddedsw.net/OpenPuff_Steganography_Home.html), but this uses LSB coupled with cryptography to provide image protection, which is very susceptible to image manipulation attacks (ie. your encapsulated message will be destroyed and the attackers become successful).